# Weird JavaScript statement, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

I see this code, what's it doing?

```
var obj = this;
```

Comment: What part of that are you confused about? [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)?

Comment: we will need to know in which context (within which function was this?)..

Comment: I think more interesting would be: Why should you do it?

Comment: Answer: It’s a [variable statement](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.2) with a variable declaration that initializes the declared variable *obj* with the value of *this*.

Answer (score 5):

It's just storing the current reference of `this` object, to be used in future. It's useful, because in JS value of `this` depends on a context.

Answer (score 3):

It saves a reference to whatever `this` was in the current context, so it can be used later.

Comment: Where "later" propably means "in closures".

Answer (score 1):

It's creating a variable 'obj' and setting it to the current context.

So, for example, if it's at a global level `this` would be the current DOM Window.

Answer (score 1):

That is setting a local copy of the current first class function that its being set in.

This is used ALOT in jquery as this takes on a different meaning when you being using the selectors.

Say I have a

```
function Person() {
   this.name = "gnostus";
}
```

and I need to access name from inside a jquery selector, where this becomes an html element, I would store my object into a copy variable and use, `obj.name` in place of `this.name` when im inside of the jquery context.

Comment: I do somehow suspect that jQuery is the context of this question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where this statement is located. It assigns to variable "obj" reference to current object.

for example the following code will open an alert window and show [Window object]. That's because we check value of "this" in the body area (not inside any objects event handler, etc.)

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert(this);
    </script>   

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = this;
```

Is stating, assign obj with the parent of the current scope.

I first read this post a couple months ago to get a handle on the keyword 'this'.

http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword is used to refer to the owner of the function , or the variable the this keyword is used in.
For a detailed understanding visit http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 0):

The only context I can think of where this sort of code makes sense is to make the current context (this) available inside a closure.

So the code would be something like:

```
var obj = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    obj.someMethod();
}, 1000);
```

That would call the method "someMethod" on the current context object after 1 second goes by.