# Why is my function not working?

Tags: javascript

Now that I have my other questions answered, this function isn't working. What's wrong?

[Weird JavaScript statement, what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461425/weird-javascript-statement-what-does-it-mean)

[How to handle click event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460733/how-to-handle-click-event-in-javascript)

```
function myFunc() {
    return
    {
        obj = this;
    };
}
```

Comment: Trying to return an object from my function.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this question to be closed, but several people have already answered it. You have two syntax errors in that function . Fix both of those, and it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is not working due to how JavaScript auto-adds semicolons.

Your `return` statement is being read by JavaScript as:

```
return;
{
    obj: this;
};
```

You need to put the `{` on the same line as `return`:

```
return{
    obj: this;
};
```

Also, objects need to be `{name: value}`.

Comment: I tried but its still not working. I don't think your stuff is right.

Comment: You are right about the semicolons, but `obj = this` isn't allowed inside an object constructor.  Only in a block.  I think the `=` needs to become a colon.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, I fixed that... I need more coffee.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax to create an object literal is:

```
{ foo: bar }
```

not

```
{ foo = bar }
```

Additionally, in JavaScript a new line can terminate a statement. By placing a new line after the `return` you are returning `undefined` and the object literal code is never reached. [JSLint](http://jslint.com) can pick up on this type of problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of semicolon injection.

This:

```
return
  { myProperty: "hello world" };
```

Is parsed like this:

```
<< return statement >>
<< pointless object literal expression >>
```

And **not** as:

```
<< return statement with return value expression >>
```

To return an object value, your code has to look like this:

```
return {
  myProperty: "hello world"
};
```

with the `{` on **the same line** as `return`.

Comment: But I have a firewall to prevent that, now what?

Comment: I think you mean semicolon insertion.

Comment: @Stack Guru, where can I get that firewall?

Comment: @Mike Samuel -- Thanks!!  I was trying to type fast :-)

Comment: Too bad you fixed your mistake too soon to be tracked by SO's revision history, now I don't know what the fuss was about. ;-)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I had originally typed "newline injection" :-)